# Can we add primary key on temp table while doing select * into #temp_table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

In a stored procedure, we are first truncating the fact table and then inserting data. The stored procedure will anyhow truncates the table first so if there are duplicates while inserting data into table, the stored procedure fails due to primary key.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE FactIncident

INSERT INTO FactIncident
    SELECT * FROM Source_table
```

So we don't have any data in the table at the end. So what I thought of doing is to first load the data into a temp table with primary key while doing

```
SELECT * INTO #temp_table
```

and then truncate and load data from temp table to actual fact table. Is it possible to add primary key while doing `select * into #temp_table` instead of creating primary key by defining `create table #temp_table` syntax?

Comment: I'd reccomend to create your #temp_table before inserting rows, in order to specify which column(s) match your primary key.

Comment: maybe you can alter the temp table after the `select into` and add the primary key then. See my updated answer.

Comment: Fix your data!  Don't fiddle around with table metadata.  Get rid of the offending rows in `source_table` that have the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

No I dont think you can have a primary key while doing `insert into` a temp table.

But if you dont want to create a temp table, you can still declare a Table variable and use that. 
Look at this example

```
declare @temp_table table (ID int primary key, name varchar(10))

insert into @temp_table values (1, 'Angela')
insert into @temp_table values (1, 'Jessica')
```

The second insert will fail due to the primary key on the temp table

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__#BD5C289__3214EC270D19E213'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.@temp_table'. The duplicate
>   key value is (1)

**EDIT:**
An alternative could be to alter the temptable after the `select into` and add a primary key constraint on column `Pcolumn`.
If adding the primary key fails, you know you have duplicates.

```
alter table #tempuser add constraint PK_TempPcolumn primary key (Pcolumn)
```

Comment: I know it's nit picking, but `@temp_table` isn't a temporary table, it's a table variable. They do operate quite differently.

Comment: Thanks. yes i know but i don't want to write create table syntax for creating temp table as we have more than 25 columns. i just want to create a temp table along with primary key in one go.

Comment: @Larnu Yes you are right. But it is different then creating a temp table as he requested in the question, allthough he probably also does not wants this either

Comment: It is different, yes, I have no arguments with that. it was more that, initially, you stated it was a temporary table. :)

Comment: @Larnu I changed that it was indeed a bit short to say it like that

Comment: If memory serves, adding named primary keys to a temp table is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need *identity* column:

```
select identity(1,1) as ID, * into #temp_table
from table t;
```

Then you can go with:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#temp_table') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #temp_table

CREATE TABLE #temp_table (Col1 INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, Col2 varchar(255), ... Col3)
```

Comment: yes but we have primary key defined on column Pcolumn. so even if i add identity column , sp will fail if there are duplicates in Pcolumn

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this to avoid errors from inserting duplicates, could you just ignore the duplicates?

```
TRUNCATE TABLE FactIncident

ALTER TABLE [FactIncident] REBUILD WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
INSERT INTO [FactIncident] SELECT * FROM Source_table
ALTER TABLE [FactIncident] REBUILD WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not yet available. Because table definition will be created internally by Database engine. Recommend not to use such T-SQL.

```
 SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM YourTable
```

is not compatible in SQL Azure. You have to create temporary table object definition first, where you can create Primary Key Column as well.